# Put Different Data Types in a Dynamic List

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[image]

I'm creating a table that dynamically adds rows, and I would like to put the input type I've already got on the server (if it's int, bool string etc) but I'd like to know how to do the field accept combobox etc

code in cshtml

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in myArrayData(her comes the data type)">
    <td>{{$index+1}}</td> <th scope="x" ng-repeat="(keycol, valcol) in x">
        <input style="width: 100%;padding: 1px 10px; margin: 8px 0; box-sizing: border-box; "
               ng-model="x[keycol]"
               ng-keyup="$event.which == 13 ? search() : null" 
               type=" this type changes">
    </th>
</tr>
```

Comment: will have given date and time also

Comment: Does your data comes with the type; like `[{name: 'column1',type:'text'}, {name: 'column2',type:'number'}]`. Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: <tr ng-repeat="x in myArrayData(her comes the data type)">
                <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
                <th scope="x" ng-repeat="(keycol, valcol) in x">
                    <input style="width: 100%;padding: 1px 10px; margin: 8px 0; box-sizing: border-box; " ng-model="x[keycol]" ng-keyup="$event.which == 13 ? search() : null" type="
this type changes">
                </th>
            </tr>

Comment: I do not know if I explained it well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this is to have a [`switch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch) on the type of the field to change between different editors for different data types.

For example, assuming your model looks like this:

```
$scope.data = [
  {name: "Joe",   type: 'A', register: 20, birthDate: new Date('2000-08-13')},
  {name: "Jeff",  type: 'A', register: 20, birthDate: new Date('2000-08-13')},
  {name: "Jimmy", type: 'B', register: 20, birthDate: new Date('2000-08-13')},
]

$scope.dataType = {
  name:      {type:'text'},
  type:      {type: 'enum', options: ['A', 'B']},
  register:  {type:'number'},
  birthDate: {type:'date'}
};
```

You can create your template like bellow:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in data">
    <td>{{$index+1}}</td>  
    <td ng-repeat="(keycol, valcol) in dataType">
      <div ng-switch="valcol.type">
        <div ng-switch-when="enum">
          <select
            ng-model="item[keycol]"
            ng-options="option as option for option in valcol.options">
          </select>
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-default>
          <input ng-model="item[keycol]" type="{{valcol.type}}">
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Even better, would be creating an editor component/directive to encapsulate the behavior, producing a different editor for the type metadata of each column, therefore making your life easier in case you want to reuse it somewhere else.

For example:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in data">
    <td ng-repeat="(keycol, valcol) in dataType">
        <editor ng-model="item[keycol]" type="valcol"></editor>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The snippet bellow implements a simple example of the problem using the solution described on this answer.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('main', function ($scope) {
    $scope.data = [
      {name: "Joe",   type: 'A', register: 20, birthDate: new Date('2000-08-13')},
      {name: "Jeff",  type: 'A', register: 20, birthDate: new Date('2000-08-13')},
      {name: "Jimmy", type: 'B', register: 20, birthDate: new Date('2000-08-13')},
    ]
    
    $scope.dataType = {
      name:      {type:'text'},
      type:      {type: 'enum', options: ['A', 'B']},
      register:  {type:'number'},
      birthDate: {type:'date'}
    };
  })
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input,
select {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1px 10px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.0/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="main">
  <table border=1>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th ng-repeat="(keycol, valcol) in dataType">
          {{keycol}}
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in data">
        <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
        <td ng-repeat="(keycol, valcol) in dataType">
          <div ng-switch="valcol.type">
            <div ng-switch-when="enum">
              <select
                ng-model="item[keycol]"
                ng-options="option as option for option in valcol.options">
              </select>
            </div>
            <div ng-switch-default>
              <input ng-model="item[keycol]" type="{{valcol.type}}">
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <pre>{{ data | json }}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, clarified the doubt, I do not know how to thank you